# Laravel where attribute of child model all in array

Tags: laravel, query-builder, eloquent

I got 2 tables: `posts` and `post_sns`

- `posts: id, title, content,..`
- `post_sns: id, post_id, sns_type`

**Relationship**: one `post` can have **many** `post_sns`.

Now I want to build a query to get all posts that have `sns_type in [2,3]`. **Not** 2 **or** 3, but **both** 2 and 3 or even more. Please help me!

Comment: And what have you already tried? Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Post::whereHas('postSns', function($q) {
    $q->where('sns_type', 2);
})->whereHas('postSns', function($q) {
    $q->where('sns_type', 3);
})->get();
```

You also need to have the relationship defined to make it work:

```
public function postSns()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostSns::class, 'post_id');
}
```

Comment: I try your method but it returns null :(
I print this query then it show: "select * from posts where exists (select * from post_sns where posts.id = post_sns.post_id and sns_type = 2 and sns_type = 3". Can you help me?
Maybe it compare with 2 and 3 one time with only one sns_type?

Comment: @NganNguyen the query looks fine. The code can't return `null`. It should return a collection of posts or just an empty collection. Please show the exact code you're using and tell me what code exactly returns `null`

Comment: Sorry, it returns empty collection. 
        $posts = Post::whereHas('postSns', function ($query) {
                $query->where('social_media_type', 3)
                    ->where('social_media_type', 5);
            })
            ->get();
In database I have:
post: id =1 / post_sns: post_id =1 , sns_type=2
                  post_id = 1, sns_type =3
it should return the post have id =1